# ASP.NET CORE 1.0, AppSettings from another assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, appsettings, asp.net-core-1.0

I have an application splittet into two projects: a web application and a class library. The `Startup` is only in the web application:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
```

I wanna have my appsettings.json in that class library and being loaded from there. Is that possible? How can I do that?

Comment: Did you want to read the whole appsettings.json or did you just want to use parts of the web application's appsetttings.json for some configuration values in the library? For the latter case I just created a configuration class in the library and a static property of this class. In the Startup.Configure I bind this property to a corresponding section in appsertings.json: `Configuration.GetSection("MyLibrarySettings").Bind(MyLibrary.Settings.Default);`.  Don't know if this is a good solution, but it is simple.

Comment: Please see my answer on this question. You shouldn't have to write any code to have your configuration accessible in another assembly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43080695/access-net-core-configuration-class-from-another-assembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, thanks Baaleos and Joe for your advices.

```
project.json

"resource": [
    "appsettings.json"
  ]
```

---

```
startup.cs

var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .Add(new SettingsConfigurationProvider("appsettings.json"))
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

this.Configuration = builder.Build();
```

---

```
namespace ClassLibrary
{
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;

    /// <summary>
    /// A JSON file based <see cref="ConfigurationProvider"/> for embedded resources.
    /// </summary>
    public class SettingsConfigurationProvider : ConfigurationProvider
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="SettingsConfigurationProvider"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">Name of the JSON configuration file.</param>
        /// <param name="optional">Determines if the configuration is optional.</param>
        public SettingsConfigurationProvider(string name)
            : this(name, false)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="SettingsConfigurationProvider"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">Name of the JSON configuration file.</param>
        /// <param name="optional">Determines if the configuration is optional.</param>
        public SettingsConfigurationProvider(string name, bool optional)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Name must be a non-empty string.", nameof(name));
            }

            this.Optional = optional;
            this.Name = name;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value that determines if this instance of <see cref="SettingsConfigurationProvider"/> is optional.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Optional { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The name of the file backing this instance of <see cref="SettingsConfigurationProvider"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public string Name { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Loads the contents of the embedded resource with name <see cref="Path"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <exception cref="FileNotFoundException">If <see cref="Optional"/> is <c>false</c> and a
        /// resource does not exist with name <see cref="Path"/>.</exception>
        public override void Load()
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SettingsConfigurationProvider));
            var resourceName = $"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{this.Name}";
            var resources = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

            if (!resources.Contains(resourceName))
            {
                if (Optional)
                {
                    Data = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException($"The configuration file with name '{this.Name}' was not found and is not optional.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (Stream settingsStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
                {
                    Load(settingsStream);
                }
            }
        }

        internal void Load(Stream stream)
        {
            JsonConfigurationFileParser parser = new JsonConfigurationFileParser();
            try
            {
                Data = parser.Parse(stream);
            }
            catch (JsonReaderException e)
            {
                string errorLine = string.Empty;
                if (stream.CanSeek)
                {
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    IEnumerable<string> fileContent;
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        fileContent = ReadLines(streamReader);
                        errorLine = RetrieveErrorContext(e, fileContent);
                    }
                }

                throw new FormatException($"Could not parse the JSON file. Error on line number '{e.LineNumber}': '{e}'.");
            }
        }

        private static string RetrieveErrorContext(JsonReaderException e, IEnumerable<string> fileContent)
        {
            string errorLine;
            if (e.LineNumber >= 2)
            {
                var errorContext = fileContent.Skip(e.LineNumber - 2).Take(2).ToList();
                errorLine = errorContext[0].Trim() + Environment.NewLine + errorContext[1].Trim();
            }
            else
            {
                var possibleLineContent = fileContent.Skip(e.LineNumber - 1).FirstOrDefault();
                errorLine = possibleLineContent ?? string.Empty;
            }

            return errorLine;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(StreamReader streamReader)
        {
            string line;
            do
            {
                line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                yield return line;
            } while (line != null);
        }
    }
}
```

You need also the [JsonConfigurationFileParser](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/JsonConfigurationFileParser.cs):

```
namespace ClassLibrary
{
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;

    internal class JsonConfigurationFileParser
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<string, string> _data = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        private readonly Stack<string> _context = new Stack<string>();
        private string _currentPath;

        private JsonTextReader _reader;

        public IDictionary<string, string> Parse(Stream input)
        {
            _data.Clear();
            _reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(input));
            _reader.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;

            var jsonConfig = JObject.Load(_reader);

            VisitJObject(jsonConfig);

            return _data;
        }

        private void VisitJObject(JObject jObject)
        {
            foreach (var property in jObject.Properties())
            {
                EnterContext(property.Name);
                VisitProperty(property);
                ExitContext();
            }
        }

        private void VisitProperty(JProperty property)
        {
            VisitToken(property.Value);
        }

        private void VisitToken(JToken token)
        {
            switch (token.Type)
            {
                case JTokenType.Object:
                    VisitJObject(token.Value<JObject>());
                    break;

                case JTokenType.Array:
                    VisitArray(token.Value<JArray>());
                    break;

                case JTokenType.Integer:
                case JTokenType.Float:
                case JTokenType.String:
                case JTokenType.Boolean:
                case JTokenType.Bytes:
                case JTokenType.Raw:
                case JTokenType.Null:
                    VisitPrimitive(token);
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new FormatException($@"
                        Unsupported JSON token '{_reader.TokenType}' was found. 
                        Path '{_reader.Path}', 
                        line {_reader.LineNumber} 
                        position {_reader.LinePosition}.");
            }
        }

        private void VisitArray(JArray array)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < array.Count; index++)
            {
                EnterContext(index.ToString());
                VisitToken(array[index]);
                ExitContext();
            }
        }

        private void VisitPrimitive(JToken data)
        {
            var key = _currentPath;

            if (_data.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                throw new FormatException($"A duplicate key '{key}' was found.");
            }
            _data[key] = data.ToString();
        }

        private void EnterContext(string context)
        {
            _context.Push(context);
            _currentPath = string.Join(Constants.KeyDelimiter, _context.Reverse());
        }

        private void ExitContext()
        {
            _context.Pop();
            _currentPath = string.Join(Constants.KeyDelimiter, _context.Reverse());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The best solution I have found requires creating a new IFileProvider and IFileInfo, and then embedding the JSON settings files in your assembly.

The solution reuses the existing AddJsonFile logic. This way you only need to tell the configuration system how and where to locate the JSON file, not how to parse it.

The solution is compatible with .NET Core 1.0.

Usage:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

        new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .AddEmbeddedJsonFile(assembly, "appsettings.json")
          .AddEmbeddedJsonFile(assembly, $"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName.ToLower()}.json")
          .Build();
    }

    ...
}
```

Embed the files by updating the project.json for the class library:

```
...
"buildOptions": {
  "embed": [
    "appsettings.json",
    "appsettings.development.json",
    "appsettings.production.json"
  ]
}
...
```

IEmbeddedFileInfo implementation:

```
public class EmbeddedFileInfo : IFileInfo
{
    private readonly Stream _fileStream;

    public EmbeddedFileInfo(string name, Stream fileStream)
    {
        if (name == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        if (fileStream == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fileStream));

        _fileStream = fileStream;

        Exists = true;
        IsDirectory = false;
        Length = fileStream.Length;
        Name = name;
        PhysicalPath = name;
        LastModified = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    }

    public Stream CreateReadStream()
    {
        return _fileStream;
    }

    public bool Exists { get; }
    public bool IsDirectory { get; }
    public long Length { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string PhysicalPath { get; }
    public DateTimeOffset LastModified { get; }
}
```

IFileInfo implementation:

```
public class EmbeddedFileProvider : IFileProvider
{
    private readonly Assembly _assembly;

    public EmbeddedFileProvider(Assembly assembly)
    {
        if (assembly == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(assembly));

        _assembly = assembly;
    }

    public IFileInfo GetFileInfo(string subpath)
    {
        string fullFileName = $"{_assembly.GetName().Name}.{subpath}";

        bool isFileEmbedded = _assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Contains(fullFileName);

        return isFileEmbedded
          ? new EmbeddedFileInfo(subpath, _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fullFileName))
          : (IFileInfo) new NotFoundFileInfo(subpath);
    }

    public IDirectoryContents GetDirectoryContents(string subpath)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IChangeToken Watch(string filter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Create the easy to use AddEmbeddedJsonFile extension method.

```
public static class ConfigurationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IConfigurationBuilder AddEmbeddedJsonFile(this IConfigurationBuilder cb,
        Assembly assembly, string name, bool optional = false)
    {
        // reload on change is not supported, always pass in false
        return cb.AddJsonFile(new EmbeddedFileProvider(assembly), name, optional, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: cebru, this is fantastic.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.1#embeddedfileprovider

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could implement [IConfigurationProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions/IConfigurationProvider.cs)

There is a base class [ConfigurationProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/ConfigurationProvider.cs) that you can inherit from then override all the virtual methods.

You can also see how the [JsonConfigurationProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/JsonConfigurationProvider.cs) is implemented.

So I guess your implementation could use the Json provider code internally against embedded json files.

Then you would also want to implement ConfigurationBuilder extension to register your provider similar as the code for using json config.

Comment: How can I embed a json file?

Comment: that is a different question than is it possible. I suggest google that new question first, then if you don't find what you need ask a new more specific question.

Comment: I only say that because I googled it and I now you can find the answer to that

Comment: @Dani See my submitted answer. The best solution, in my opinion, is embedding the JSON files.

Answer (score 1):

Someone else can correct me, but I don't think what you are looking for exists.
App Configs and AppSettings files are read at runtime by the application that is running.

The Class Library cannot see any AppSettings specific to itself, because when it runs at run time, it is in the folder of the running application.

The only potential way I can see for you to get your class library contain the json file, is to have the json file as an embedded resource.
Eg: In the solution, select the json file, and set it to Embedded Resource instead of 'content'.

The problem becomes getting the embedded config file out of your assembly, and then loaded.

AddJsonFile accepts a path to the json file.

You could however extract the Json file to a temp directory, then load from there.

```
static byte[] StreamToBytes(Stream input)
            {

                int capacity = input.CanSeek ? (int)input.Length : 0; 
                using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream(capacity))
                {
                    int readLength;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[capacity/*4096*/];  //An array of bytes
                    do
                    {
                        readLength = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);   //Read the memory data, into the buffer
                        output.Write(buffer, 0, readLength);
                    }
                    while (readLength != 0); //Do all this while the readLength is not 0
                    return output.ToArray();  //When finished, return the finished MemoryStream object as an array.
                }

            }



Assembly yourAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyTypeWithinAssembly));
using (Stream input = yourAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("NameSpace.Resources.Config.json")) // Acquire the dll from local memory/resources.
                {
                    byte[] byteData  = StreamToBytes(input);
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)+"//Config.json",new byte[]{});
                }



var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile(Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)+"//Config.json");
```

You should in theory be able to specify a type from the class library, in order to help the c# code target that class library specifically. Then you just need to provide the namespace and path to the embedded json file.